# Are there any protocol enhancements for Flash Of Un X?

Tags: javascript, performance, protocols, progressive-enhancement, spdy

My question is simple:

Are there any (existing or planned) enhancements to the HTTP/SPDY protocols, or extensions which have been written to enable browsers to modify their rendering routine such that Flash of Un-Whatever Content can be hidden from the user?

Of course, IE users will be behind everyone else, but this I think would be a sensible enhancement to the wire protocol, requiring only an extra couple bytes or so, and cutting down on a fair bit of extra JS rendering.

Or would this strategy fly in the face of the general Progressive Enhancement philosophy?

As noted in the comments, this can be implemented as a third party extension, or would it be better to implement as a centralized standard?

Comment: Wouldn't this be an appropriate question for the respective design committees?

Comment: So you mean the server should take out the blocked elements?

Comment: Certainly, if you would be so kind to point me to the 'respective design committees' - where/what would I want to do? E-mail the W3C? And having worked with and implemented HTTP 1.1 protocol extensions, this doesn't have to be done by a committee - I could and may write such an extension myself, and could even hack on the FF browser to get this implemented.

Comment: So are you saying, say, if I blocked Flash: a) Flash elements should be removed b) HTML5 should be chosen when available and Flash parts not sent c) Flash content should not be requested d) Something else? a and b sound difficult to implement as part of HTTP/SPDY — it’s very HTML-centric, no? — and as for c, that’s already the case. So I’m not sure what you’re proposing.

Comment: @minitech I'm not sure you understand my question at all. Progressive enhancement refers to a specific Javascript technique, not Flash/HTML5, Flash of Un-X is a generic way of referring to a browser 'bug' where the naive implementation results in two or more different pages appearing for a split second thanks to separately styled versions of the page being progressively loaded, thanks to parallel page loading and other page loading optimization techniques. It has nothing to do with Flash Player elements or Adobe.

Comment: Sorry, never heard it quite like that. So how do you expect HTTP to deal with this, exactly?

Comment: @minitech Well the idea is that pages could send a couple extra bytes to the browser in the http headers, as an extension, letting the browser know to wait for a signal from javascript that the page has finished loading, optionally with a timeout so the user isn't stalled waiting for a crashed script. Until then the user would be greeted with some other screen, whether it be a client side loading screen, a server supplied one (maybe a picture sent over the wire, or a cached loading screen?) This is instead of the current situation where some browsers will display this flash of unstyled 'x'.

Comment: A picture sent over the wire would make a whole lot of stuff a lot slower, and there’s a reason most design handbooks you’ll find strongly discourage splash screens. Does it make anything faster? If not, I can’t imagine users care. (UX tip, too: people like it better when something is loading *visibly*. And if a cached page stays up too long, it’s just frustrating [since browser progress bars are about as inaccurate as it gets, as far as the intuitive behaviour goes]).

Comment: The picture is just an idea/option, and it would be a one-off transaction, so it wouldn't really make anything slower beyond the intial load. With regards to the loading tips, perhaps that's true that people want to see it loading. So are you saying that the UX answer to this question is that people WANT to see Flash of Un X? Whether that be a page looking progressively nicer or functionality loading over time. The time we're talking about is, as the name suggests, a 'flash' so the browser wouldn't be displaying the 'loading' or 'blank' screen for more than a fraction of a second anyways.

Comment: Would it make anything faster? Yes, it would delay the render process of the browser, so that it doesn't waste time or compute cycles rendering a bit of content that's going to change in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Imports would be one such feature:

> HTML Imports block rendering of the main page. This is similar to what `<link rel="stylesheet">` does. The reason the browser blocks rendering on stylesheets in the first place is to minimize flash of unstyled content (FOUC). HTML Imports behave similarly because they can contain stylsheets.
>
> With this change, all `document.write` output from `<script>` tags inside HTML imports go to the imported HTML documents. This eliminates the problem of the HTML imports clearing the main page.

Link prerender would be another:

> IE11 can prerender one page in the background. If a second prerender request is encountered, it replaces the first request. Additional prerender requests are ignored.

```
<link rel="prerender" href="http://example.com/" />
```

> Developers can fine-tune the way that IE11 prioritizes resource download. The built in priority scheme may not be sufficient for some Web pages. For example, developers may want to indicate that images located below the fold should be prioritized lower than more important resources located above the fold.

And the IE specific `lazyload` attribute is a third:

> Developers can lower the priority of a resource by adding the lazyload tag:

```
<img src="image.jpg" lazyload  />
```

And finally, the `defer` and `async` attributes of the `<script>` element:

```
Usage   	 	 	 	 	 Description

<script src="widgets.js"></script> 	 	 The script is executed immediately, and the page waits for the script to finish before continuing to parse. This can significantly reduce page-load performance.

<script async src="widgets.js"></script> 	 The script is downloaded asynchronously while the page continues to parse. The script executes after the download has completed.

<script defer src="widgets.js"></script> 	 The script is executed when the page is finished with the parsing.

<script async defer src="widgets.js"></script> 	 The async attribute is honored, and the defer attribute is ignored. This enables developers to use async in browsers that support it, but fall back to defer in browsers that don't support async.
```

**References**

- [HTML Imports: #include for the web](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)
- [Async Ads with HTML Imports](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/11/16/async-ads-with-html-imports/)
- [Prerender and prefetch support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn265039)
- [Resource Priorities Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-priorities/)
- [Asynchronous script execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673524)